# argparse required argument list competes with optional argument list

Tags: python, argparse

I have a Python program with argparse. The required arguments are list of filenames, and optional are a list of strings that are to be removed from all files.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("File formatter")
parser.add_argument("filename", type=str, nargs="+")

parser.add_argument("-r", "--remove", metavar="STRING", nargs="+")

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.filename)
print(args.remove)
```

The above gives

```
usage: filefmt [-h] [-r STRING [STRING ...]] filename [filename ...]
```

The problem: In a call like

```
filefmt -r str1x gg24 a.txt b.dat
```

the program has no way of knowing which of the arguments is a remove `STRING` and which a `filename`. I'd have to call it like this

```
filefmt a.txt b.dat -r str1x gg24
```

but sometimes, environments require me that the filenames come last.

Any idea how to fix this? I'd like to avoid having to prefix the filenames with an option string, this is the default use:

```
filefmt a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: You’ll have to require the -r for each string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the ambiguity you'll have to require the -r option for each STRING

For example:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("File formatter")
parser.add_argument("filename", type=str, nargs="+")

parser.add_argument("-r", "--remove", metavar="STRING", default=[], action='append', help='string to remove (repeat this option for each string)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.filename)
print(args.remove)
```

Run like this:

```
args1.py -r a -r b qwe asd zcx
```

output:

```
['qwe', 'asd', 'zcx']
['a', 'b']
```

The usage doesn't show you can repeat the -r so I added that in the help for -r:

```
usage: File formatter [-h] [-r STRING] filename [filename ...]

positional arguments:
  filename

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -r STRING, --remove STRING
                        string to remove (repeat this option for each string)
```